# Source and exe out of sync: commented line seems to call function in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am fairly new to GDB debugging and am struggling on the following: I need to know when a function endpage() is called, so I set a breakpoint on it using

```
(gdb) b endpage
```

I run the program, hit the breakpoint and have a look at the call stack:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  endpage () at ./szreptf.c:652
#1  0x0807ef91 in _repstr (s=0x80ac780 "") at mntrep.c:1818
#2  0x0807eef9 in repstr (s=0x80aa0f0 "") at mntrep.c:1798
[...]
#9  0x08052894 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfb01994) at ./szmainf.c:514
```

And the call of this function is a commented line, and empty at that !

```
(gdb) l mntrep.c:1818
1813    //  extern int pdf_page_length;     /* sydenham - imanage project */
1814    //#endif /*I_MANAGE_SITE*/
1815    //
1816    //  if( !repcanwrite() )                
1817    //      return;
1818    //       
1819    //  if( keychst() == 'Q' && rep.pfquit != NULLFN)
1820    //      (*rep.pfquit)(); // Calls endpage() in szreptf.c 
1821    //  
1822    //  if( rep.on == 'C' )
```

This line wasn't originally commented, but I tried to see whether GDB was looking at the right file, and it is: any change I make in that file, I can see it in GDB with the l command.

But for some reason endpage() is still called out of the blue, so it looks like GDB shows me a file that is not the one I compiled.

**So my question is:** how does GDB decides which file to display when debugging ? I thought it was inferred from the executable, but apparently it is not the case.

Any clues ?

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** I forgot to mention it, but I attached GDB to a running program, I didn't start the program with GDB.

Comment: The debugging information in the executable doesn't include the source code itself -- just *filename:linenr* pairs. Therefore GDB will always display whatever the file looks like right now, which might not match the compiled code if you modified the source code after compiling.

Comment: So GDB got the call stack directly from the executable but the source code from my working directory ? It makes sense, only I did compile the file just before running it. I'm gonna edit my question, I forgot to mention that I am attaching GDB to an already running program.

Comment: Whether it's an already running program or not makes no difference in this case. GDB always gets the source code locations (but not the source code itself) from the debugging information in the executable file.